# Text editor: if certain key pressed want to cancel key event and give new functionality

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I have a `JEditorPane` with text/html type. When an enter key is pressed with the editor focused, I want to do some checks about the state of the document and then override the enter key default functionality if conditions are met.

I believe this can be done with a `KeyListener` listening for a key, then consume the event if conditions are met to cancel the key making any change to the input. Testing this idea I'm just trying to consume the key event when any key is pressed. The key listener below is printing output when i press any key, but the characters are still getting inserted into the editor pane.

How can I stop the characters getting inserted altogether?

Thanks for your help.

```
String content = "";
String type = "text/html";
editor = new JEditorPane(type, content);
editor.setEditorKit(new HTMLEditorKit());
editor.setEditable(true);
editor.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
panel.add(editor);

editor.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        System.out.println("huh?");
        e.consume();
    }
});
```

EDIT----------

Removed key listener, and added instead

```
Action enter = new AbstractAction()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("enter!");
        if ( condition == true ){
             // default enter key behaviour
        }
    }
};
editor.getActionMap().put("insert-break", enter);
```

Ok I got rid of the KeyListener and added this, which prevents the default enter-key functionality which is great. But how would i insert a break (the default enter key behaviour) if my if clause is true?

Comment: Don't use a KeyListener. Swing was designed to be used with `Key Bindiings`. Key bindings work by associating an `Action` with a `KeyStroke`. In this case all you need to do is replace the default `Action` with your custom `Action`. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29542611/131872 for an example using a JTextArea. The concept is the same for a JEditorPane.

Comment: @camickr Ok that works, thanks! When i decide that I want to let the default enter functionality through (and insert a line break), how would I modify the code? I edited the question

Comment: Save the original Action and invoke it manually as required.

Comment: Ok thank you I will give that a try

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to do do that. I can store the previous action I believe with Action previousEnter = editor.getActionMap().get("insert-break"); before assigning the new "insert-break" action, but then I can't figure out how to trigger that on the editor programmatically. Something like "editor.fireAction(previousEnter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't figure out how to trigger that on the editor programmatically.

You are over thinking it.

We save the `Action` because we want to invoke the `actionPerformed(...)` method of the `Action`.

Assuming the original `Action` is stored in the variable "original" the code would be:

```
if (condition == true)    
    original.actionPerformed( e );
```